# Converting a java object to both XML and JSON not producing consistent output

Tags: java, xml, json, xstream

I am trying to convert a java object within an ArrayList into both XML and JSON strings and then send it over to ActiveMQ server.

For converting to XML I am using XStream API and for converting to JSON I am using Google GSON API. I want to have consistent output after conversion in both the cases which I don't see here. One of them is showing the  tag and the entire package name  whereas the other one completely omits both.

Is there any standard conversion API available that I can use which actually converts the input object to a consistent output format for both XML and JSON?

```
Input Object (ArrayList containing some POJO):
==================
eventsLst = [PageViewEvent{pageName=Home Page, pageType=Home}]


    XML Conversion (Using XStream):
    ====================================
    <list>
      <com.istore.event.model.PageViewEvent>
        <pageName>Home Page</pageName>
        <pageType>Home</pageType>
      </com.istore.event.model.PageViewEvent>
    </list>

    JSON Conversion (Using GSON):
    ========================================
    [{"pageName":"Home Page","pageType":"Home"}]
```

Comment: You'd have to define what you mean by _consistent_. What should the `<com.istore.event.model.PageViewEvent>` node be instead?

Comment: Instead of the fully qualified class name is just want the class name and also don't want the <list> tag.

Comment: You look closed at XStream tutorial.

Comment: I know that there are ways to handle this but I am more inclined towards using a common technology for handling this scenario rather that using two different jars(xstream.jar and google-gson.jar) from two completely different providers.